# REST based Polymer app

Tags: javascript, polymer, web-component

I would like to create a client app for my RESTful service. I really like the idea of Polymer, but I am not able to find some complex example how to write a Polymer rest service handler.

I am new to Polymer so any help is appreciated

Comment: I think, Polymer is just a View in the MVC pattern, so you need some system like Backbone( or better Marionette), you can change the default View system and use Polymer

Answer (score 1):

Polymer has an element called core-ajax that handles this. I have used it on the page linked below, check it out:

https://github.com/IntrinsicSchools/student-portal/blob/master/client/app/elements/kickboard-behaviors.html

Comment: Thanks, now I am a little closer to undestand that each element is actualy a model. Can you help me how can I connect these models? If  the user logs in, than he has different menu links. How can I set some global attributes for all models?

Answer (score 0):

The core-ajax element (https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/core-elements.html#core-ajax) provides a custom element wrapper for using XMLHttpRequest & at least one example of handling a service response. Other than that you can really do this any way you'd like.